# Slicing plots generated by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder if it's possible to slice a graph respectively a .png file generated with ggsave. If I do not want to use the default legend ort title and set it to FALSE it leaves me with a lot of white space. So is there an R way to just cut the file several pixels above and below the graph itself?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 7):

You could change the `plot.margin`, e.g.

```
p + opts(plot.margin=unit(c(-1, 0, -1, 0), "lines"))
```

Since version 0.9.2 `opts` has been [replaced](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) by `theme`:

```
p + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-1, 0, -1, -), "lines"))
```

Comment: Thx, great idea! ggplot is so hilarious, all these options are really impressive. 
Though I can't really control my graph's bottom margin so far... (using "cm").

Comment: does this margin work like css margin / padding definitions ? I was able to look up "unit" but could not figure out how top,bottom,left,right works in this case.