# ggplot: How to increase spacing between faceted plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several faceted histograms (obtained with the command below) which are nicely plotted one under the other. I would like to increase the spacing between them, however, they are tight.

I looked at the [doc](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/facet_grid.html) but didn't find a parameter for this.

```
qplot (Happiness.Level, Number.of.Answers, data=mydata, geom="histogram") + facet_grid (Location ~ .)
```

Comment: A side comment that I found another way to approach this (used a faced_wrap instead of facet_grid and the resulting chart is better looking). I'm still interested if there is a way to address the original question.

Comment: Try theme_get() for a slew of hidden options that you can adjust with opts()

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Use the [theme](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) function:

```
library(grid)

p + theme(panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines"))
```

See also here: [Slicing plots generated by ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491421/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252750/alter-just-horizontal-spacing-between-facets-ggplot2

Comment: Due to another update, the incantation is now `theme(panel.margin = unit(2, "lines"))`

Comment: Update - is now `theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"))`

Comment: This works without the ``grid`` package. In my experience the x labels of two side-by-side plots often overlap (the greatest label on the lhs and the smallest label on the rhs). One solution to fix the output is to ``ggsave`` with a greater width than the default. But I find ``theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"))`` nicer because it also works for the pop-up plot window.

Comment: I was getting an error "Error: widths must be a unit object" but changing from "lines" to "pt" worked as in `theme(panel.spacing = unit(15, "pt")`.

Answer (score 45):

Just to add to @rcs response:

```
# Change spacing between facets on both axis
p + theme(panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines"))

# Change horizontal spacing between facets
p + theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(2, "lines"))

# Change vertical spacing between facets
p + theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(2, "lines"))
```