# ggplot: How to override the ylim interval?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a faceted plot (about which I had this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681647/ggplot-how-to-increase-spacing-between-faceted-plots) question). I would like to control the interval of ylim() to reduce the clutter because it looks like this:

[image]

It's too detailed and I would like to display only 0 and 500, that is *not even the maximum* (the thin horizontal lines are enough). The reasons I want only those 2 values are:

- reduce the granularity (the values every 200 are crammed vertically)
- by avoid 1000 there will be more space between 0 and the next value belonging to the facet plot below.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I see the sequence of your questions, I believe you better take a good look at the help files first. Go through all the material here : http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/  Also the answer on this question is easily found in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the following to your code. you can tweak it based on what labels you want displayed on the y-axis.

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 500))
```