# Alter just horizontal spacing between facets (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

`ggplot2` has the ability to change the margins between a faceted plot using the argument `panel.margin` in `opts`.  This seems to change both horizontal and vertical spacing.  Is there a way to change the spacing of either horizontal or vertical without changing the other?

**An example with outcome and desired outcome:**

```
mtcars[, c("cyl", "am", "gear")] <- lapply(mtcars[, c("cyl", "am", "gear")], as.factor)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, group = cyl)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color=cyl)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape=cyl)) + 
    facet_grid(gear ~ am) +
    theme_bw()        

p + opts(panel.margin = unit(1, "lines"))
```

So it currently looks like:[image]

How can we make it look more like:[image]

Comment: I would have guessed you could use the four arguments for top, right, bottom and left margin but you can't. Bummer.

Comment: @lselzer, I thought so too, but I think that option is only for `plot.margin`. This feature [was asked about](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ggplot2/tMQsVb5P69s/discussion) a year ago, with the answer to its availability being "not at present".

Comment: Since the ggplot2 0.9.2 now replaces `opts` with `theme` and you can move some things independent of another (ie `panel.grid.major.y` etc) I figured this may work to use: `theme(panel.margin.x = unit(1, "lines"))` but it does not.

Comment: Submitted an issue requesting this: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/678

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As of July 9th, 2015, the `panel.margin.x` and `panel.margin.y` seem to have been implemented

```
p <- p + theme(panel.margin.x=unit(0.5, "lines") , panel.margin.y=unit(1,"lines"))
```

As of December 15, 2016, 'panel.spacing' and 'panel.spacing.x' is implemented in r 3.3.2 and ggplot2 2.2.0

```
p <- p + theme(panel.spacing.x=unit(0.5, "lines"),panel.spacing.y=unit(1, "lines"))
```

Comment: What does the "lines" mean?

Comment: "lines" is a unit of size. Check `?unit`, it shows "lines" is a valid unit along with "inches", "cm", and more.

Answer (score 9):

A manual solution until this feature becomes available:

```
library(grid)
height <- 0.5 # Vertical spacing
aux <- 1e-5 # Auxiliary number to identify 'height' among other heights
width <- 0.1 # Desirable horizontal spacing

p <- p + theme(panel.margin = unit(height + aux, "lines"))

gtable <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gtable$widths[sapply(gtable$widths, '[[', 1) == height + aux][[1]][[1]] <- width
grid.draw(gtable)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  Hopefully we see this available in the future.