# CairoPNG increases text size outside plot margins

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization, cairo

I have a chart created with `ggplot2` and I'd like to use `CairoPNG` because especially when creating pie chart `png` and `jpeg` create a very pixilated image. The problem is that `CairoPNG` seems to modify the text size and so, especially in the legend, the text of one key overlaps other key, or, like in the above

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Cairo)

df <- data.frame(id=c("IMPORT VALUES YTD", "EXPORT VALUE YTD"),
                 value=c(6,4))

chart <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=factor(1), y=value, fill=factor(id)),
           stat="identity", width = 1, color="white") +
  coord_polar(theta="y")  +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.position="top",
        legend.text=element_text(size=14))

CairoPNG("test1.png", 350, 400)
chart
dev.off()
```

[image]

```
png("test2.png", 350, 400)
chart
dev.off()
```

[image]

Do you know how to avoid this?

Comment: From your two outputs it's not obvious to me that the size of the text is different. The quality of the text rendition is clearly different though (and it might not be the same font exactly).

Comment: same or not they do occupy more space... in fact they don't fit into the plot

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround adapted from @rcs [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491421/slicing-plots-generated-by-ggplot2/3491580#3491580). 
Add to your code:

```
library(grid)
```

and inside `theme` block:

```
plot.margin = unit(c(0,2,0,0), "lines")
```

[image]

Comment: Note you **maybe** have either an extra "s" on import valuES or an missing "s" on export valuE. If the former, then, your previous code already would work with one less character in the legend-title.

Comment: Hi! thanks a lot. Yes, it is a typo... sorry. However this does not help when the left key overlaps the right one. My workaround is paste()ing each level with `"   "`. I was actually after some parameter to trigger in `CairoPNG` to avoid that. But it seems more tricky than that.